# Setting mouse sensitivity in GLFW

Tags: c++, mouseevent, glfw

I am making this C++ program with rectangles on it that's needed to be drag whether horizontally or vertically by clicking on them and checking if other rectangles will collide onto it.
Now, in my situation, I have this case that if the user moves the mouse very fast. The collision detection won't work, I mean, `the other coordinates are skipped out or jump out on a very large distance`. I am assuming that adding mouse sensitivity on my program can change this unwanted behavior.

I use `GLFW` for windowing. I think `glfwSetMousePos()` can do what I want but I don't know what math should I apply to attain this. And if possible, I don't want to use other libraries. Can someone show some code how could I do this?

Thanks!

**Update**

Sadly to know, mouse sensitivity is not the issue in my case. I think I can work this around by expanding my code with lots of  `if`. However, for those who are looking for this kind of question, I suggest [this](http://en.sharejs.com/cpp/20113). You can use it as a separate program by just running that code.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a collision detection algorithm that handles penetration at any speed.

Look into sweeping collision detection.  It's pretty much how all physics engines work.